# iOS playing cards

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, playing-cards

I currently have an image which has every suit and value of a deck of playing cards in it. There is an UIImageView to show this picture, with width and height set to show just one card at a time and view mode set to "top left" so it doesn't stretch.

[image]

Now I'm just showing what happens to be the top left card, the ace of clubs. I tried finding a way to offset the view to show a different portion of the UIImage, but couldn't find a suitable property (tried fiddling with "frame" and "bounds").

Is there a way to get such an offset working, or am I going about this the wrong way? I'd like to keep all the cards in one image in "sprite sheet" style so that they would be easy to modify later instead of having a bunch of separate pics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the bounds to what you'd like to show, enable 'clipToBounds' and make sure the content stretch mode is set properly. That should work.

EDIT: I do recommend making different images though, because of memory issues (even though not the whole image is shown, you still fully have it in memory).

Comment: Just to expand on what mirage said -- probably the most robust thing is to write a program that splits the big image into 52 smaller images.  Then have your app work with the small images only.  Now you will have the best of both worlds.  If you need to make changes, you can make them on the big image, then run your splitter program to create the small ones and feed those into your app.